# How to use instagram api with guzzle 6+ and laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, instagram-api, guzzle

Im trying to convert this url `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=123456789`

Into something I can use with guzzle. So far I've got:

```
$token = "123456789";    
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/', [
        'access_token' => $token
    ]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // 200
    echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'
```

but I just get an error that reads:

```
Client error: `GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthParameterException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Missing client_id or access_token URL (truncated...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your token in `query` like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $client->get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/', [
    'query' => [
        'access_token' => $token
    ]
]);

return $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks, It returns data but then I get this error `ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186:
cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'access_token' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)` after the json.

Comment: Sorry @Rifki, It was actually a different function that caused the error. Your answer worked! Thanks.